# Are there security or other issues with changing PHP time limit and max input vars?

Tags: php

A developer that created some specialty apps/scripts has requested we increase PHP time limit from 30 to 50,000.  Plus, they want PHP max input vars to go from 1,000 to 5,000.

What are the implications of these changes on our WordPress installation?  Will it run more slowly?  Are there security implications?  Are the custom scripts just poorly coded to need these changes?

Thank you.